# AJAX is not passing hard-coded data

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, ajax

In `index.js` I have:

```
 $("#weather_form").on("submit", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/weather/",
      type: "POST",
      data: {type_of_person: "1",
        exercise: "2",
        unit: "3",
        zip_postal: "4"},
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "json",
      success: function (data){
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        alert("errmsg: " + errmsg + "\nerr: " + err + "\nxhr.status: " + xhr.status + "\nxhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

So we know it's going into the error function of the AJAX call because of the popup. But why?

I specifically hard-coded the JSON values to pass.

**The view that processes the AJAX data:**

```
class weather(base.TemplateView):
    template_name = "weather/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = forms.input_form()
        return context

    @staticmethod
    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = forms.input_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data
            type_of_person = form.cleaned_data["type_of_person"]
            exercise = form.cleaned_data["exercise"]
            unit = form.cleaned_data["unit"]
            zip_postal = form.cleaned_data["zip_postal"]

            results_matrix = interface.get_results_matrix(type_of_person, unit, exercise, zip_postal)
           
            return http.JsonResponse({"results_matrix": results_matrix.tolist()}, status=200)
        else:
            return http.JsonResponse({"error": form.errors}, status=400)
```

**Things I've tried, but to no avail:**

- `data: JSON.stringify({type_of_person: "1", exercise: "2", unit: "3", zip_postal: "4"})`

Comment: Show us views where you are sending data

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane  Done! I updated with the view that is processing the AJAX data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the form could not read data as you are sending `contentType` of `json`. Just removing that line should work. Also, you have to add `csrf` header to post request. So:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/weather/",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        "type_of_person": "1",
        "exercise": "2",
        "unit": "3",
        "zip_postal": "4"
      },
      dataType: "json",
      // contentType: "json", remove this
      success: function (data){
        alert("success");
      },
      error: function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        alert("errmsg: " + errmsg + "\nerr: " + err + "\nxhr.status: " + xhr.status + "\nxhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, that worked! What's the difference between `dataType` and `contentType`?

Comment: Well, `contentType` is the data we are sending to the the server and `dataType` is type of data sent from the server or the response data. See [here](https://qawithexperts.com/questions/115/what-does-content-type-and-data-type-mean-in-jquery-ajax-req) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't make sense to call `success` if you're receiving a 400 status code from the server.

Your data is valid in frontend and goes to the server, but it does not pass backend validations (or the backend fails to accept it properly) and therefore it returns you 400 Bad Request.

Any error code that is between 200-299 and different than 304 is considered an error when making an jQuery AJAX call.